# Split string using boost::algorithm::split_regex

Tags: c++, boost-regex

I'm trying to split a string by using `;` as delimiter but not when it is escaped `\;`. The string can contain characters, numbers, and nested quotes. I'm currently using boost::algorithm::split_regex like so:

```
string data = "hello; world; 100444; \"Hello \\; world\";";
vector<string> data_vec;

boost::algorithm::split_regex( data_vec, data, boost::regex("[^\\\\];");
```

I have tried to use negation but that didn't have any effect. `boost::regex("(?:[^\\\\]);")`

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) `(?<!regex)` like this

`(?<!\\\\);`